# Error kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL with Alamofire

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

I am sending a request to the server using `Alamofire` but I am getting following error :

```
NSURLSession/NSURLConnection HTTP load failed (kCFStreamErrorDomainSSL, -9802)
```

My Code to hit the api

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), { () -> Void in


        let manager = Alamofire.Manager.sharedInstance

        manager.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60

        Alamofire.request(.POST, path, parameters:self.dataDict,encoding: .JSON, headers:headers).responseJSON { (responseData) -> Void in
          if((responseData.result.value) != nil) {
               //code
            }
         })
```

After searching on the net, I have added `NSTransportSecuritySetting -> AllowArbitaryLoads` to YES in `info.plist`. But still getting this error.
Any help?

Comment: working on device?

Comment: Share your code for better understanding, without code we can't help you

Comment: iOS9 requires the server to only support TLSv1.2.

Comment: Working with simulator ...

Answer (score 0):

try this may be working because iOS9 requires the server to only support TLSv1.2.

Add The syntax for the Info.plist configuration looks like this:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
<dict>
  <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
  <dict>
    <key>yourserver.com</key>
    <dict>
      <!--Include to allow subdomains-->
      <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to allow insecure HTTP requests-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionAllowsInsecureHTTPLoads</key>
      <true/>
      <!--Include to specify minimum TLS version-->
      <key>NSTemporaryExceptionMinimumTLSVersion</key>
      <string>TLSv1.1</string>
    </dict>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

iOS 9 require TLSv1.2 SSL for all hosts you plan to request data from unless you specify exception domains in your app’s Info.plist file.